# Using jquery to show time every 3 seconds does not work properly

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I am very new at "*jsp*" and "*jquery*", I think the code below should display a number on screen and increase it by one every 3 seconds, but after 2 or 3 repetitions it breaks and starts to show wrong numbers

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(
                function () {
                    $('#load_me').load('index.jsp').fadeIn("fast");
                }, 3000); // autorefresh the content of the div after
        //every 3000 milliseconds(3sec)
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<%! int i = 0;%>
<div id="load_me">
    <%out.print(++i);%>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I even tried to show time instead of printing a number, but the same problem accrued :

```
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(
                function () {
                    $('#load_me').load('index.jsp').fadeIn("fast");
                }, 3000); // autorefresh the content of the div after
        //every 3000 milliseconds(3sec)
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="load_me">
    <%
        Date d = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sp = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
        String t= sp.format(d);
        out.print(t);
    %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code below works for time showing, but you have to create date.jsp page,

```
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(
                function () {
                    $('#load_me').load('date.jsp').fadeIn("slow");
                }, 3000); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="load_me">
<%@ include file="date.jsp"%>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

date.jsp :

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
</head>
<body>
<%
    Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sp = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    String t= sp.format(d);
    out.print(t);
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

it seems you want a 'div#load_me' should display a number increment of 1 every 3 seconds.. Try the following plain javaScript for the same:

```
setInterval((function() {
var currNumber = 0;
return function() {
document.getElementById('load_me').innerHTML = ++currNumber;
}
})(), 3000);
```

**EDIT (To demonstrate the full code) :**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- we do not need jquery any more :-) -->
</head>
<body>
<div id="load_me">

</div>
<script>
setInterval((function() {
    var currNumber = 0;
    return function() {
    document.getElementById('load_me').innerHTML = ++currNumber;
    }
    })(), 3000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this way you can avoid the unnecessary server calls as well.

Comment: It works very nice, thanks, but could you please tell me what was the problem with my code, because I am trying to learn jquery

Comment: Both the sample of codes posted by you are trying fetching some index.jsp for painting the 'div#load_me'. And this involves the network round trip as well, which might be causing the inconsistency in your output.

Comment: How can I refresh the whole page by the same way ?